# TextWriterTraceListener or StreamWriter for logging?

Tags: c#, performance

I'm trying to decide whether to use TextWriterTraceListener or StreamWriter to write my log files. In the company I work for some people use one and some use the other, but nobody can explain to me the real difference between the two. I also did some research on the issue, but nowhere does anyone do a good job of explaining the differences. I understand that TextWriterTraceListener can be instantiated without actually opening the file, which seems to give it a leg up on StreamWriter.

I am curious what people think/know about this? Is one faster than the other? Does one handle file locking better? Why choose one over the other?

Comment: IMHO neigher is better, I will choose a proper logging framework

Comment: @oleksii what framework would you choose?

Comment: I have used log4net which is rock solid and stable, but there are others, like nlog, enterprise library logging block

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main advantage of `TextWriterTraceListener` is that it allows you to turn on or off the logging *without recompilation*.  You can deploy your application with the logging (via trace calls) in place, and change the configuration to include a `TraceWriterTraceListener` via app.Config.

Internally, it just routes the trace log calls to a `TextWriter`, so there isn't an improvement in terms of performance, etc.  It's more a matter of flexibility.

If performance is critical, it's better to use ETW Events instead of the .NET trace writing mechanisms or File IO.  For details, see this tutorial on [Logging ETW events in C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2012/07/09/logging-your-own-etw-events-in-c-system-diagnostics-tracing-eventsource.aspx).  Event Tracing for Windows (ETW) provides an incredibly high performance mechanism for event logging, which can be enabled and disabled at runtime for specific applications on an as-needed basis (and combined with other ETW sources).